# I am unable to delete file from the s3 using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, delete-file

I use following method to delete uploaded file from s3

```
key = params[:folder_name]+'/'+params[:file_name]
            resp = S3_BUCKET.delete_object({
              bucket: "My-s3bucket", 
              key: key
            })
```

I get the error :
NoMethodError (undefined method `delete_object')

I also use S3_BUCKET.object(key).delete but this also gives error like:
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0))

I define s3_bucket as bellow

s3_file = AWS::S3.new( :access_key_id => 'access_key_id', :secret_access_key => 'secretkey')
S3_BUCKET = s3_file.buckets['My-s3bucket']

Please help me when i was going wrong

Comment: Can you share your S3_BUCKET definition here. Seems like an issue in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution that is as following

```
object = S3_BUCKET.objects[key]
object.delete
```

It is works for me